# Will replacing == with ===, or != with !== possibly break anything in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I randomly ran JSHint against some existing Javascript that i didn't write. There a few hundred instances of:

```
Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.
Expected '!==' and instead saw '!='.
```

I know that Javascript suffers from type coersion; which nobody should *ever* rely on. That's why it's recommended that you **never** use `==` (since it wasn't what you wanted) and instead use `===`. It's also why you should never use `!=` (since it wasn't what you wanted) and instead use `!==`.

So, there's code i didn't write. I don't know what it does. I don't know how to reach it in order to test it. But since it's bad practice to use `==` and `!=`, and i know why it's bad practice, i should convert them to the alternate syntax.

Unless it will break things.

Is it absolutely, guaranteed, 100%, no chance that existing code could suddenly not work?

Or can it breaks things?

Because if it can break things, then they won't be getting touched; and the project will die of old age like that.

Comment: Sure, if you're depending on implict type conversions. e.g. `'0' == 0` is TRUE, `'0' === 0` is FALSE.

Comment: Since the `==` && `===` can give different results with the *same* inputs then it's safe to say that this *could* break things.

Comment: If you have to ask this question, you should not set out on the project of blindly converting your code. JavaScript doesn't "suffer" from type coercion; it's simply part of the language, and it definitely has its uses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is quite possible that it will break something in your JavaScript as `==` and `===` perform two different operations and aren't necessarily interchangeable.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you're comparing.

`===` means 'is equal and the same type', where as `==` does implicit type conversion if necessary before comparing the values.

It can definitely break things if there are conditional statements that rely on these operators.

Answer (score 2):

It depends. If you rely on the loose comparison in JS. So if both `some_var == 0` and `some_var == "0"` should evaulate to true, than it would break. If you want to check, if it is the string "0" than you have to use `===`.

So yes, it might break something but it might also fix some wrong evaulations.

Comment: Don't forget that `var` is a keyword!

Answer (score 2):

#### Yes, changing those operators could break things.

However, using the "strict" forms (`===` and `!==`) is generally accepted as a best-practice since their behavior is more predictable than the "standard" non-strict (`==` and `!=`) forms.

The key issue is that the `==` and `!=` operators perform [type conversion (see docs)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Using_the_Equality_Operators) whereas `===` and `!==` do not.

Consider the following examples:

```javascript
'0' ==  0 // => true
'0' === 0 // => false

'1' !=  1 // => false
'1' !== 1 // => true
```

Answer (score 0):

If two values are not the same type `===` will return false where `==` would return true. Therefore `===` might return a different result than `==`, depending on what you are comparing in your code.